# 12 or 24 volts for longer run time

Tags: batteries

I know the difference in series and parallel and 12 or 24 volts it's a simple concept.
   What i would like to know is, which gives more run time on their respective inverters or does 24 volt just reduce draw from batteries?
   I will be buying a 1200 watt inverter 12 or 24 and only using it for aprox. 900 watts for a few hours at a time.

Comment: My gut says the 24V inverter is likely to be more efficient (run longer) because the conduction losses in the Mosfets will be lower but this is not guaranteed as switching losses may be higher. Check the datasheets for both.  However, this question is off-topic on this site as it is not about design but a product recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule the higher the source voltage the more efficient the MOSFETs are at converting one voltage to another, or to AC. It has to do with current flow through wires and the MOSFETs and the transformer.

If you double the source voltage you could say you need just half the amps to get the same wattage output, but you also gain a few percent more efficiency in the conversion process.

That is one of the reasons many portable UPS systems use two 12 volt batteries in series, not in parallel. If they were in parallel the converter would have to work harder to overcome DC resistance to the higher current, which would be wasted away as heat.

There is talk of 36 and/or 48 volt car voltages, as the manufactures could use smaller gauge wire, so less copper and less cost in copper and weight. (For exposed wiring UL limits the voltage to 48 VDC or 36 VAC in the US, as this starts to create a mild shock if touched.)

Another example of why a higher source voltage makes for a more efficient converter; The Toyota Prius uses a 200 volt battery which it can boost to 500 volts to pass up a slow driver. A 200 volt source makes for a very efficient buck/boost converter.

Answer (score 0):

The run time does not depend directly on the battery voltage. To first order, the run time depends on how much energy is stored in the battery. The amount of energy in the battery is roughly equal to the battery voltage times the ampere-hour rating of the battery. The product of this multiplication will have units of watt-hours. It sounds like you want something like 3000 watt-hours out of the inverter so you'll need to make sure the battery has at least that much energy. If it were me, I'd want to have at least 50% more energy in the battery than I expected out of the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example, two 12 volt 100 Ah batteries, you should get the same run time with them connected in parallel (for 12 volts, 200 aH) with a 12 volt inverter, as you would with them in series (for 24 volts, 100 aH) with a 24 volt inverter.

Comment: As long as they are matched series works just as well. But like any 6 cell battery if one goes dead , the whole battery cannot work so parallel operation is more reliable in the long term.

Comment: If one cell in a battery is bad, it will affect the resulting pack, whether the batteries are in series or parallel. (I've had a shorted cell in one of two parallel batteries - could not fully charge the pack as a result.)

Comment: Agreed,  cell shorts from dendrites may be as common in some cells as opens from imbalance rapid aging

Answer (score 0):

24v will give you lower line losses, which could also factor in to runtime if the length of your conductors from the battery to the inverter are substantial.
This is assuming you are comparing a 12v and 24v battery with equal AH ratings and a 12v to a 24v inverter with equal efficiency ratings (even from the same brand, one may have higher efficiency than the other at the load range you intend to run it at.